# Android XML Layout - percentage + wrap_content

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to make some part of layout like ex.:

```
[_____EditText1_____] / [_____EditText2_____]
```

and I didn't want to set width in dp/px etc.
I want to wrap_content fo width for 'slash' sign "/" and divide remaining width for (50% to 50%) for EditText1 and EditText2.
It's simple for only EditText1 and EditText2, just setting in both of them:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight=".5"
```

but how to set TextView "/" and for width wrap_content, between two EditTexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

   <EditText
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight=".5"
   />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="/" />
 <EditText
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight=".5"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.48" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/"
        android:layout_weight="0.04" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.48" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/"/>

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`TextView` will occupy its space and the remainning will be distributed among `EditView`s equally.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

The key is to increase `layout_weight` value of the middle element ;)